# Android. SQLite некорректно работает SELECT WHERE

Tags: android

Получил странное поведение SQLite на Android.

Выполняю запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE company_id = 8
```

и получаю 0 результатов, хотя строки с `company_id` равным 8 есть!

---

Для проверки решил сделать иначе. На запрос

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE company_id = 8 OR company_id = 1
```

получил строки с `company_id = 1` и `company_id = 8`. А на запрос

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE company_id = 1
```

получил строки *только* с `company_id = 1`.

---

Код запроса:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DBContract.ObjectEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, filter, 
                         null, null, null, null,null );
```

`filter` - это `company_id = 8 OR company_id = 1`.

Где я допустил ошибку? 
Через SQLite DB Browser все работает.

Прикладываю базу:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ijguvfkhaa73rb/azs.db?dl=0

Программа-смотрелка
http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: скачал базу, открыл в sqliteman и запрос работает как ожидается, записи возвращает.

Comment: На Android не работает как надо.

Comment: Попробуйте `raw` запрос, который `rawQuery()`

Comment: У меня есть несколько вариантов, но они все выглядят дико. К примеру, в записи company_id буковка о - кириллическая.

Comment: Вы уверенны что на телефоне такая же база как вы приложили?

Comment: @anber Именно такая. И трюк с выборкой по id 1 или 8 срабатывает.

Comment: @KoVadim подойдут любые варианты, даже самые дикие :) Буква О НЕ кириллическая, название колонки менять пробовал.

Comment: @Evgeniy, ошибок я тоже не нашел. База в порядке, в консоли sqlite3 на хосте запрос работает верно. Проверь 3 раза flter, вдруг у тебя там случайно OR закрался, когда его не должно быть. Попробуй подставить там константную строку. Или ещё вариант попробовать company_id = 1 OR 0.

Comment: Значит нужно собрать минимальный пример кода, на котором воспроизводиться указанная бага. Это можно сделать так - взять исходную программу и удалять с нее все, что не касается указанной проблемы. Потом запаковать в архив  и выложить куда-либо.

Вполне возможно, что в процессе удаления кода оно "неожиданно заработает".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очистил данные приложения, удалил его, сбросил номер версии базы до 1 поставил - внезапно запустилось и правильно работает.

Comment: @ReinRaus и? посмотрите на время добавления моего коммента, потом на историю правок ответа - что там было написано 3 часа назад.

Comment: @PashaPash извините.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать метод rawQuery вместо query, в этом методе напрямую можно указать строку запроса как с SQL-студии. Хороший пример [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/77-urok-37-zaprosy-iz-svjazannyh-tablits-inner-join-v-sqlite-metod-rawquery.html)

Comment: Изначально так и было и также не работало.